# semantic-ui sortable table not getting sorted

Tags: jquery, frontend, semantic-ui

I am using semantic-ui 1.8.1

I created a sortable table as documented at http://semantic-ui.com/collections/table.html#sortable

The table however does not get sorted when i click on the table column headers.

I have included the file

I was able to reproduce this on jsfiddle also. The link is `http://jsfiddle.net/4woemsjt/5/`

This despite that I have included the file `tablesort.js` and also specified the class `"ui sortable celled table"` on the table

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this javascript call

```
$('.sortable.table').tablesort();
```